# Unity 3D: How to stop/reset 2D sprite animation after releasing key?

Tags: unity, 2d, animation, sprites

Im following a tutorial to create animations with a 2D sprite character.
But i put in my own. Which has 8 animation positions. 
For some reason when my guy walks around,then stop, the walkings animation continues to play out then resets to idles.

I need the animation to reset as soon as i release the key.

Im using Animator if you are wondering.

EDITED: 
Original video with all the keys for each animations.
[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZpuvTS9gTI)

Second video with only 2 keys per animation, it was a test.
[Second Video Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGH4H9bXyDk)

Code Snipet!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;

private Animator _animator;
private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody2D;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    _animator = GetComponent <Animator>();
    _rigidbody2D = GetComponent <Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    CheckDirection();
}

void CheckDirection(){
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A))
    {
        WalkAnimation(-1,0,true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D))
    {
        WalkAnimation(1,0,true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W))
    {
        WalkAnimation(0,1,true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S))
    {
        WalkAnimation(0,-1,true);
    }
    else 
    {
        _animator.SetBool("Walking", false);
    }
}

void FixedUpdate (){
    Move();
}

void Move(){
    float dirX = _animator.GetFloat("VelX");
    float dirY = _animator.GetFloat("VelY");
    bool walking = _animator.GetBool("Walking");

    if (walking)
    {
        _rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(dirX,dirY) * speed;
    }
    else
    {
        _rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
}


void WalkAnimation (float x, float y, bool walking){
    _animator.SetFloat("VelX", x);
    _animator.SetFloat("VelY", y);
    _animator.SetBool("Walking", walking);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your transition to have immediate effect you need to make sure that **Has Exit Time** is not checked in your transition.

Has Exit Time determines whether the transition’s condition can take effect at any time, or only during the state’s exit time.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html

[image: has exit time]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Animation class. According to [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animation.Stop.html) page, calling

```
animation.Stop("%%animationName%%");
```

will stop animation.

Comment: i dont use animation class.